# I've found about 40 kilograms of beige powder labelled "Green Salt" - what is it?

Tags: identification

I've found this in my neighbourhood, near a trash trolley:
[image: Container with label]
The handwriting can be unambiguously translated from Hebrew as "Green Salt".

My best bet is that it is some kind of fertiliser because that would be cheap enough to throw away once you're done with and I found it outside a newly renovated garden.

Here's what it looks like inside:
[image: Inside view]

And here's a closer look:
[image: Closer look]

It has a definitely organic smell. I'm not sure what of, though.

Google suggests this is either Uranium tetrafluoride or Magnus' green salt.

What do you think it may be?

Why was it used for and why was it thrown away?

Would it be useful to me in any way?

Is it toxic?

Is it flammable?

Is it a fertiliser?

Is it sell-able?

Comment: Without a sample being analyzed at a lab it is unwise to guess.  Labels can say anything but I would not consider putting anything in my garden that I was not sure of it's origins.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible the stuff is actually "GreenSAND?"  If so, that is a legit organic soil amendment.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greensand

However, I agree with those who say don't put it in your garden unless you are absolutely certain of what it is.  Not worth the risk, imo.

Comment: It has a definitely organic smell. I'm not sure what of, though.

Answer (score 3):

If it was abandoned and looks suspicious i think you should report it to local police or environmental authorities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be either of the things you've discovered on Google - for a start, what's in that bag isn't green, and both the chemicals you mention are green in colour when in this condition.

Why its labelled green salt is a mystery, but if you're feeling brave, see if there's any aroma to the contents of the bag, in case its a fertiliser such as fish, blood and bone. From its appearance in the picture, it just looks like soft sand.

That said, I certainly wouldn't use it, as Kevinski says - I'd be more concerned to find out how to get rid of it, so I'd probably wheel it right back to where it came from.

Comment: It has a definitely organic smell. Not sure what of, though.

Comment: @ShaharOr - probably is an organic soil amendment of some sort then, but I still wouldn't use it without knowing for sure what it was, as Teresa says.